# Visual Studio Create Script setting ignores Target Platform

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

For my database project, I put the tick on the Create script (.sql file) in my Project Settings. And Target Platform is set to SQL Server 2008. I have SQL Server 2012 installed on my machine. But the script its generating only works in SQL Server 2012, doesn't work in SQL 2008 at all. Is there a way to generate the script for SQL Server 2008? I'm surprised it's using whatever is installed locally and ignoring the Target Platform setting.

Comment: Can you give us some more info? What is the output that doesn't work on 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SSDT:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2fdffc00-055c-487d-827d-f17b751dc5cd/ssdt-generates-2012-option-for-target-2008-when-target-is-a-dacpac?forum=ssdt#60de8e54-02a8-4983-a1d5-7f44766a167b

I have a deployment contributor which removes those invalid options. You can get it here: http://scardevblog.blogspot.com/2015/03/ssdt-generates-2012-option-for-target.html